# Get the value of the pressed button for QMessageBox addButton function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmessagebox

I am trying to write a function to better manage QMessageBoxes for the program I am designing. It takes a number of parameters and creates a custom QMessageBox based on those parameters.

```
def alert(**kwargs):
    # Initialization
    msg = QMessageBox()
    try:
        # Conditioning for user selection of QMessageBox Properties
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            key = key.lower()

            # Set TitleBox value
            if key == "title":
                msg.setWindowTitle(value)

            # Set TextBox value
            elif key == "text":
                msg.setText(value)

            # Set Custom Buttons
            elif key == "buttons":
                buttons = value.split(',')
                for x in range(len(buttons)):
                    msg.addButton(QPushButton(buttons[x]), QMessageBox.ActionRole)

        msg.exec_()

    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
```

A simple form this function would be called will be like this:

```
alert(title="Some Title", text="Some Text", buttons="Yes,No,Restore,Config")
```

However, I am having trouble getting the value of the pressed button. I have tried the following solution but it did not fix my problem.

1. ```
      msg.buttonClicked.connect(someFunction)
   ```

This would pass the value of the button to a function, but I want to access the value of the clicked button in my alert() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the clickedButton() method that returns the pressed button.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox, QPushButton


def alert(**kwargs):
    # Initialization
    msg = QMessageBox()
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        key = key.lower()
        if key == "title":
            msg.setWindowTitle(value)
        elif key == "text":
            msg.setText(value)
        elif key == "buttons":
            for text in value.split(","):
                button = QPushButton(text.strip())
                msg.addButton(button, QMessageBox.ActionRole)
    msg.exec_()
    button = msg.clickedButton()
    if button is not None:
        return button.text()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    text = alert(title="Some Title", text="Some Text", buttons="Yes,No,Restore,Config")
    print(text)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly how I wanted it to.